# IE8 Javascript error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why IE8 fails on this function?

```
function checkExist(arr, val) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == val) <-- "Object doesn't support this property or method"
            return true;  
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay, the obvious question: What's in `arr`? Although frankly I have a lot of trouble believing that that line of code throws that error, unless `arr` contains objects you've defined that override `toString` or `valueOf` and, in *those* functions, does something using a method or property that doesn't exist. Walk through with the debugger built into IE8 and find out where the error is *really* happening.

Comment: it dosent matter what inside arr,the function is not even called.

Comment: @ Max: You edited the question to show that it *was* the `==` line. Either it is or it isn't. Find out which.

Comment: If you mean that `checkExist` is not even called, then the error is not inside that function.

Comment: The only guess I have is that you are passing an `Object` that has a length attribute but does not have any numeric attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing something that **is not** an array as `arr` parameter. Check what `console.log(arr);` will display if you put it as first line in your function.